# How to execute 2 sucessive system command in c using system() like connecting to ftp and logging in using program?

Tags: c++, c, ftp, command, system

I want to use the ftp command using system function in c. I need to execute 3 commands.

1 FTP 
2 USERNAME
3 PASSWORD

how do i perform the above 3 using system().... i am stucked up here 
 system(ftp);

Comment: You can't easily use `system` to do that.

Comment: What have you tried? People here will help you solve issues but not write code for you.

Comment: Username ans password are not separate commands, but input to the ftp tool. While it is possible to run the ftp client and send commands to it from C, a much easier solution would be to connect to the server from your program, either using sockets directly or getting a library to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using some other API instead of system(). System() is considered as non standard way for supplying commands.
I would suggest use only FTP command for opening that terminal and then use ftp apis overs winsock api's.

These are few library I know. please use if,

```
libftp 
ftplib
```

enough documentation can be found in web for this.
Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check if your version of `ftp` allows you to specify the user name and password on the command line (some do). Of course, you could also implement ftp either on your own (using sockets directly), or via a library (there are several around).

Otherwise, if you really want to run the system's `ftp` command, you probably want to use `popen` (or, on Windows, `_popen`) instead.

```
FILE *cmd = popen("cmd", "w");

if (NULL != cmd)
    fprintf(cmd, "%s\n%s", user_name, password);
```

What you write to the `FILE *` goes to the standard input of the child process (and if you open with `"r"` instead of `"w"`, you can read from the child's standard output). Many (but not all) recent versions of `popen` also support `"rw"`, so you can write to the child's standard input and read from its standard output.

Note, however, that this will only work for a child process that reads from its standard input. Some use other methods to read directly from the console/keyboard, and it won't (necessarily) work with those.

Comment: Also, the stream must be closed with `pclose()`. For apps that read directly from the console/keyboard, you could use `forkpty()` and `exec*()`.